# XSLT grouping via for-each-group and group-starting-with?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to create group for below example. Element 'ques' and just following-sibling::p make inside the 'group' element
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<title>Title</title>
<p>para</p>
<ques>Ques</ques>
<p>aaaa</p>
<fig>aaa</fig>
<box>box</box>
<ques>Ques</ques>
<p>aaaa</p>
<p>bbbb</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code:**

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ques">
            <group>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
  <title>Title</title>
  <p>para</p>
  <group>
    <ques>Ques</ques>
    <p>para</p>
  </group>
  <fig>fig</fig>
  <box>box</box>
  <group>
    <ques>Ques</ques>
    <p>para</p>
    <p>para</p>
  </group>
</root>
```

**Link:**
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVQdo6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try perhaps something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="ques">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="self::ques or self::p">    
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::ques">
                        <group>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </group>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```